Is there a location in the universe with the minimum rate of time dilation?
According to general relativity, time dilation occurs due to strong gravitational fields and high relative velocities, causing time to pass more slowly compared to observers in weaker gravitational fields or lower velocities.
However, my question is kind of the opposite - is there a specific location or region in the observable universe where the rate of time dilation is minimized, meaning time passes at the fastest rate compared to any other point?
In other words, is there a point or area of the universe that could be considered a "time dilation minimum" where the effects of gravitational fields and relative velocities are the weakest, allowing for the most rapid passage of time from that reference frame relative to any other point?

Time dilation always compares the rate at which time flows in two places. So your question would need to be are there two spots with the minimum difference? It seems a trivial answer would be right here and right here.

@mmesser314 of course, but I'm asking for a point relative to "all" other points. You could imagine calculating average the time dilation over the first point and all other points in space time. Assuming this, where should be my first point to minimize this average time dilation?

Hm, looks like you are asking for the center of the universe. Good luck!

@GyroGearloose I'm not very interested on where it is, does it even exist?

That location you mean should be the event horizon of a black hole.

Sounds like the answer should be more like a void, although it's not clear to me that this can be answered in an objective, coordinate-independent way. In synchronous gauge there is no time dilation anywhere.

@JanG no that's the opposite of what I mean.

@Sten yes exactly. The first obvious thing is that It shouldn't be near any object (since gravitational field eventually causes time dilation). The coordinates however, that's the difficult part to find out.

@AmirhosseinRezaei,. Ups, I have mistaken your question. It should be some location in a void. Interestingly,  in all points of the void the time dilatation would be the same.

Yes, it's called the Axis of Evil!

For anyone who's wondering: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_evil_(cosmology)#:~:text=The%20%22axis%20of%20evil%22%20is,cosmic%20microwave%20background%20(CMB).

I'd recommend you also right an answer. @Fattie

The universe is, to the best of our current knowledge, both isotropic and homogenous at large scales. So there will be no one point that is singled out at cosmological scales. All that would matter is the nearby distribution of matter, with “nearby” being defined at cosmological scales. So you just want a region in the middle of a large void.
Velocities are relative. So “at rest” is the least time dilation, however you define “at rest”.

@AmirhosseinRezaei thanks for the upvote. That put me over 100k!

Perhaps then "The Bootes Void" is a good answer

 This question actually has more of a "physiological" answer than of a "scientific" answer. The notion of dime dilation is frame-dependent. Let's say you are a moving observer. You can consider yourself at rest, and the entire universe is moving with respect to you. So, you conclude that because you are at rest, you experience the least time dilation. The same goes for any other observer. Only you could know that you have experienced more time dilation is when you stop, thus your absurd change of reference will cause more time to be passed in your frame. So, if there is a body that is always in motion in the universe (that most of the bodies actually do, for instance the voyagers, they will be in motion for many billion years), the notion that  who experiences least time dilation  becomes relative.
